# How to get youtube to continuously play on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'd just like to have an embeded youtube player that runs the user's playlist on iPhone/iPad.
Whatever I've tried so far the player just stops after one song.

Answer (score 0):

The place to start is [the Google YouTube Dev page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#control-video-playback).

That said, it is not the place to end - they try to provide instruction for both iOS and Android in the same breath/docs, and the examples are a tad on the obsolete side. Perhaps I or someone else could provide a more helpful answer if you  could you provide more detail on what you have tried so far?